# Batch file with changing drive letters

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

My goal is to create a batch file that will extract the contents of a zip file to a separate directory.  Every file related to this question is on the same flash drive.

The following command works just fine with the drive letter `i:\`

```
**i:\7z x i:\zips\new_app.zip -oi:\apps\new_app**
```

What happens if I put the flash drive into a different computer and the drive letter is NOT `i:\` but `f:\` or `g:\` or `q:\`

Is there some sort of variable I can create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `I:\` with `%CD%`. The `%CD%` environmental variable holds the current directory path.

```
%CD%\7z x %CD%\zips\new_app.zip -o%CD%\apps\new_app
```

Upon double-clicking the batch file, it starts in the directory it resides in. If the batch file is in the root of the USB stick, `%CD%` will be set to `I:\` or whatever drive letter the USB stick got mounted as.

Comment: Perfect. For others I will add that I didn't need the / after the %

Answer (score 0):

If you run the .BAT file from the USB drive you don't need to specify the drive letter, only the path and/or file relative to the .BAT file.

Example: If Unzip.BAT is in the root of the USB Drive and the .zip is in a folder called "classified docs" under a folder called "secret" it would be

```
\secret\classified docs\
```

Comment: I can't get the command version of 7zip to accept that though.  When I use the -o it wants a drive letter after it.....unless I'm doing it wrong....which could also be true.

Comment: Ahh, that could be problematic. I don't know enough about 7zip to make any further suggestions. I think Rain there has the answer though as that should work.

Answer (score 0):

This design can be used from within the folder structure:

```
"%cd:~0,2%\<full path>"
```